# Postgres CAST macaddr

Tags: postgresql, casting

Lets say I have two tables in Postgres:

```
Name: table_rad
Column    Type   
id        integer
username  character varying(64)

Name: table_mac
Column    Type
id        integer
mac       macaddr
```

I want to do to a join:

```
SELECT * FROM table_rad WHERE username = mac;
```

Postgres will complain:

```
ERROR: operator does no exist: character varying = macaddr
LINE 1: ...ELECT * from table_rad WHERE username = mac;
                                                 ^    
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Sofar I have googled for a solution and I know I have to CAST. But how can I cast type macaddr as varhcar?

Comment: How can a mac address be the same as a username? You surely have very strange usernames then...

Comment: This is quite normal in the RADIUS world when one wants to use mac-based authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formal style: `CAST(mac AS varchar)`

PostgreSQL-style: `mac::varchar`

e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM table_rad JOIN table_mac ON username = CAST(mac AS varchar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `::text` like below:

```
SELECT * FROM table_rad WHERE username = mac::text;
```